# Composition of more than one camera

Tags: camera, compositing-nodes

I'm using 3 cameras, and what to have different composition to each camera, I learned how to change the composition but it's work for all the cameras together, how can i separate them?

**EDIT:**
Maybe it wasn't clear, I'm use more than 1 camera.
I need one of the cameras to show the result that seen in *Composite* and other camera to show the result of *Composite2*.

[image]

How can I config the cameras differently? or maybe it should be done in other way?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want. I am assuming that you want to switch between the cameras, am I right? If so I will post an answer.

Comment: Thanks you @EricXue, I want to take 3 images with 3 different cameras, that each of the cameras have it own compositing flow. Is it clear explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for *susu* answer I have started to check what View Layer is about, some why for me it didn't work (may be I'm doing something wrong). Anyway just next to it  their is Scene menu, I tried to add a new scene and it's solve my problem. Each scene have it own Compositing, so I'm taking one image  when first scene is active then change the active scene and take the  second image. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Each camera would need to be in a different view layer.

There can only be one active composite node on the compositor, that would be the output image set in the output section of the properties window.

If you need more than one output use file output nodes, add one file output node to each of the view layers you need